# Check if a string contains another string in R when strings contain special characters

Tags: r, data.table

In R, using `data.table`, I was testing if a string contains another string as follows:

```
library(data.table)
string1 <- "AAAAA"
string2 <- "AAA"
print(string1 %like% string2)
```

The above returns TRUE. But when string looks like

```
string1 <- "(A)_"
string2 <- "(A)_"
print(string1 %like% string2)
```

The above returns FALSE.

Is there any way to fix this other than removing special charaters?

Comment: Edited to clarify that you are using data.table. Please correct if I was mistaken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the `%like%` operator, you can use the `like` function, which has additional arguments.

One of those arguments is `fixed`, which allows you to ignore regular expressions. So:

```
like("(A)_", "(A)_", fixed = TRUE)
```

returns `TRUE`.

Note that this is identical to how `grepl` behaves, which is the more common `base` version of `like`.

Answer (score 2):

`` ?`%like%` ``  reveals that:

> Internally, like is essentially a wrapper around base::grepl

If you treat `string2` as a regular expression by escaping any characters that represent special characters in a regular expression the comparison will yield the result you expect (`TRUE`)

```r
string1 <- "(A)_"
string2 <- "\\(A\\)_"
print(string1 %like% string2)
```